# UpdatePanel with TextBox.OnTextChanged Async Event not firing

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a textbox for inputting a desired username.  When the user types in their name and the input loses focus, I want to send an async postback to check whether their username is already taken.  This works fine in the cases that no error is thrown, but I want to handle errors, as well.

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx), I've added an AsyncPostBackError handler to the ScriptManager.  I've tried this both on every page load and only on non-postback page loads.

I have my TextBox in an UpdatePanel like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLogin" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbLogin" runat="server" placeholder="username" 
            OnTextChanged="tbLogin_TextChanged" required />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbLogin" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code-behind, I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackError +=
        BootstrapLogin_AsyncPostBackError;
}

void BootstrapLogin_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)
{
    tbLogin.Attributes.Remove("data-success");
    tbLogin.Attributes["data-error-message"] = myErrorMessage;
}

protected void tbLogin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("what?");
}
```

I also added `Async="true"` to my Default.aspx Page markup.

When I have `AutoPostBack="true"` on my TextBox, the error is thrown and the AsyncPostBackError handler is never called.  For some reason, during the postback, `Page.IsAsync` is false.  I suspect this is the reason (or indication of why) it's not being handled.

When I set `AutoPostBack="false"`, no postback is fired at all, despite the specified trigger.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: The error is merely whatever exception I throw.  So in this case, the error is "what?" :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like following code doesn't work as intended

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackError +=
        BootstrapLogin_AsyncPostBackError;
```

Instead of that I just set the `OnAsyncPostBackError` property of the `ScriptManager` in markup and it worked with `AutoPostback = "True"` in your `TextBox`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" OnAsyncPostBackError="BootstrapLogin_AsyncPostBackError"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Not sure why your code didn't work. It picks up the correct ScriptManager.

**UPDATE**

Solved it!
I should refresh my knowledge on Page lifecycle :(

Actually, we should add your code into `Page_Init` rather than in `Page_Load`. Following works perfectly.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AsyncPostBackError +=
                BootstrapLogin_AsyncPostBackError;
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

See this screen capture

[image]

Hope this helped!

Comment: I bet that would do it, but I don't have access to the ScriptManager markup.  :(

Comment: Don't be sad. there's a solution for every problem :P See my update. By the way, I'm just curious, why don't you have access to ScriptManager markup?

Comment: Did you use AutoPostBack="true" or "false"?  Moving it to Page_Init didn't change it from the behavior I originally posted.

Comment: AutoPostback = "True". I don't have the Async="true" in my page though

Comment: See the screen capture

Comment: It did not.  I suspect my issue lies in some config file or in some code in the framework I'm using that I don't have access to.